# Shliach Tzibbur that says "HaKel HaKodesh" instead of "HaMelech"

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, mistakes, aseres-yemei-teshuva

What should be done in a case where the shliach tzibbur when davening chazaras ha'shatz makes a mistake and instead of saying "HaMelech HaKodesh" during Eseres Yamei Teshuva he says "HaKel HaKodesh". Normally the halacha by a yichud if the person has already gone further in Shemoneh Esrei and realizes this mistake they have to go back to the beginning of the Shemoneh Esrei. By a shliach tzibbur if this was realized after a point where it cannot be corrected must the shliach tzibbur start over again chazaras ha'shatz?

Answer (score 6):

One who errs in this regard must start over from the beginning (*Shulchan Aruch*, OC 582:1). The *Beit Yosef* implies that this applies to a *sh'liach tzibbur*, as well (OC 582:2). The *Sha'arei T'shuvah*, quoting the *Z'kan Aharon* (§ 6), rules explicitly that the *sh'liach tzibbur* must return to the beginning, and must repeat *k'dushah*, as well (OC 582:1).

Comment: +1 As I recall, the Meiri holds that the Sha"tz is an exception because Kedusha constitutes a break-marker in the "first three". He is a daat yachid though IIRC.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Nice. A citation would be great if possible, too. +1 on the comment.

Comment: Fascinating Meiri, but the standard halacha is that any mistake deemed "critical" to the individual is critical to the Chazzan's repetition as well. I saw a chazzan who said "ha-Kel", and then tried to save face by repeating slowly and clearly - "BARUCH ATA HASHEM" -- which wasted his 2-second opportunity, forcing him back to the first bracha.

Comment: @Shalom , Fred : Found it! My search also led me to a teshuva of Rav Ovadia, both of which I've added in a separate answer.

Comment: The first Shaarei Teshuva to that Siman rules this way explicitly.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I read the *Sha'arei T'shuvah*, and it rules explicity that the *sh'liach tzibbur* must return to the beginning. That's what you meant, right?

Comment: @Fred Yes I see now I was unclear. I meant "this way" meaning the approach of your answer as opposed to the approach in my answer. That's why I thought it was better to edit it into this one.

Answer (score 5):

The Meiri (Brachot 34a) rules that a Chazzan who makes such a mistake need only go back to Attah Kadosh (=LeDor VaDor for Ashkenazim).

Rav Ovadia Yosef has a Teshuva (Yabia Omer OC 1:8) where he goes through much of the literature on the matter and concludes in accordance with this opinion.

Comment: +1. Sounds like you are also on track to answer [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20347/).

Comment: @Fred Possibly, I want to reread and double check his reasoning to see if it would apply to a yachid. I'll hopefully get a chance to check tomorrow, bli neder or shevua or issur or konam or cheirem or shamta or arur or nezriut.

Comment: I was concerned about nezirut.