# Saying HaKel HaKadosh (when must say "HaMelech") and not going back to beginning of tefillah

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, aseres-yemei-teshuva

When a person says "HaKel HaKadosh" instead of "HaMelech HaKadosh" during Aseres Yemei Teshuva  the halacha is they must go back to the beginning of the tefillah and start over again. What would be the din of the person didn't go back to the beginning but rather said the bracha of "Atah Kadosh" over again with "HaMelech HaKadosh" and then continued davening normally. Would this be ok b'dieved or would they have to start the whole tefillah over again after finishing?

Comment: maybe related https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%93

Answer (score 1):

This is not a special עשרת ימי תשובה law, but a general law that the first three Brachos are seen as one unit. The last three as well.

If one makes a mistake in a Bracha he needs to return to the beginning of that Bracha. If a mistake is made in one of the first three - he returns to the beginning of the three, which is the beginning of 18.

(**EDIT**) Hence, if one fails to fix the Bracha which was messed up - the whole Tfila should be said again.

Rambam, Tefila 10:1:

```
מי שטעה באחת משלוש ברכות הראשונות חוזר לראש
ואם טעה באחת משלוש אחרונות חוזר לעבודה
ואם טעה באחת מן האמצעיות חוזר לתחילת הברכה שטעה בה
```

**EDIT**

A friend pointed out [Rav Ovadia](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_677_6.pdf) saying that a *shatz* during *chazara* should return to third bracha. However, he explains this is because during *chazara* the 3-bracha-unit ends after *kedusha*, so there's no need to go to beginning. A *yachid* should go to beginning. Other *poskim* do not agree with this psak (I've seen Rav M. Eliyahu explicitly).

(P.S. The friend argued that if it was possible to return to 3rd bracha only that's what the psak would be since we make a *bracha levatala* (on the first two *brachot*) doing otherwise. I'm unsure about this point.)

Comment: But what if they didn't do that?

Comment: What @DoubleAA said. The part of this answer that's relevant to the question merely repeats the premise already stated as the first sentence of the question. −1.

Comment: Obviously, re- _daven_.

Comment: @JNF, not obvious to me. Can you argue the case, or cite a source?

Comment: The answer is in the Rambam. It's one unit and he must go back. +1 from me.

Comment: @msh210, if one makes a mistake in any bracha the whole davenning doesn't count and should be redavenned. If one notices this in middle of davenning he has the chance of fixing it, by the rules brought above. If he didn't fix it that way - he needs to do the whole thing again.

Comment: That's one way to read the _Rambam_. The other is that he must go back to the start: but going back to "_Ata kadosh_" suffices _b'diavad_. The _halacha_ you cite is already impliedly known to the asker above; any source for the _b'diavad_ case?

Comment: @msh210, do you have a source explaining the Rambam that if a mistake is made in one of the three first Brachos the other two are OK?

Comment: I have no source for _either_ claim of what happens _b'diavad_: that's why I didn't pen an answer.

Comment: @msh210 apparently poskim agree that if the above rules set by Rambam weren't followed the whole davenning should be redone. I hope you'd agree regarding the last rule. I see no reason to say the other two are different. Going back to _Hakel Hakadosh_ doesn't fix it.

Comment: @msh210, it's just like going back to the middle of ברכת השנים after saying ותן טל ומטר during the summer.

Comment: A more precise source for R. Ovadiah's psak is his Yechaveh Daat (vol. 6 §38).

Answer (score 0):

The KafHaChiam ([יעקב חיים סופר](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Chaim_Sofer)) says ([582:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.582.9?lang=he)) that *as long as* you have not started the next Bracha, בדיעבד, you could still change and say המלך הקדוש - and there’d be no need to restart the Bracha, just fix it.

> ט) נראה דבדיעבד אם שהה יותר מכדי דיבור יכול לומר המלך הקדוש כל זמן
>   שעדיין לא התחיל בברכה שלאחריה משום ספק ברכות אבל אם לא נזכר עד שהתחיל
>   בברכה שלאחריה אפי' תיבה אחת צריך לחזור לראש וכמ"ש באו' שאח"ז.